# BigQuery standard SQL : checking if an array is null does not work

Tags: google-bigquery

If i launch this query :

```
with a as (
select cast(null as array<string>) as x union all select ['str1','str2'] as x)
select * from a where x is null
```

I get this result :

[image]

This is the result i expected.

But if i first launch this query :

```
 select cast(null as array<string>) as x union all select ['str1', 'str2'] as x
```

whose result i save in a table "a" in a dataset "tmp" and then i launch this query :

```
select * from `tmp.a` where x is null
```

I get this result :

[image]

I expected a result identical to the first one. Why is there a difference between the two results ?

Comment: I think this is related to the fact that you can't really have NULL arrays. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197380/unnesting-and-reforming-a-big-query-array-seems-to-destroy-null

Answer (score 30):

Workaround : To get the same result for both cases you could use in your where clause the function `ARRAY_LENGTH(x)=0`.

Answer (score 0):

From official documentation

```
Currently, all existing data types are nullable, but conditions apply for ARRAYs.
```

```
An ARRAY can be NULL.
For example:

SELECT CAST(NULL AS ARRAY<INT64>) IS NULL AS array_is_null;

+---------------+
| array_is_null |
+---------------+
| TRUE          |
+---------------+
```

```
BigQuery translates a NULL ARRAY into an empty ARRAY in the query result, although inside the query, NULL and empty ARRAYs are two distinct values.

WITH Items AS (
  SELECT [] AS numbers UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS ARRAY<INT64>))
SELECT numbers FROM Items;

+---------+
| numbers |
+---------+
| []      |
| []      |
+---------+
```

TL;DR: An array can be null but if you check it with where condition it will act if it is not null. If you want a truly empty array you have to cast it `CAST(NULL AS ARRAY<INT64>)`. You can see my example below.

[image] [image]