# Unnesting and reforming a big query array seems to destroy null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT foo FROM UNNEST(CAST(NULL as ARRAY<STRING>)) as foo) is null
```

returns false

vs.

```
SELECT CAST(NULL as ARRAY<STRING>) is null
```

returns true

My specific situation is that I'd like to sort an array using

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT foo from UNNEST(bar) as foo Order by foo) as arr
```

and keep the array as null if it was originally null. I'm open to alternatives for sorting the array but preserving null (meaning I'm not hung up on my implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *empty* array is different from a `NULL` with an array type.  An empty array is an array with no elements.  That is what you get from the `UNNEST()`.  So, the comparison to `NULL` is false.

The second is returning `NULL` typed as an array.  This is equivalent to `NULL`, so the comparison is true.

Comment: Got it. I'm used to a world where any operation on a NULL would result in a NULL....

Comment: This is still true. But an array with a null element is not itself null.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard . . . Arrays in BQ do not have `NULL` elements.  An *empty* array is not `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was trying to explain to the OP that operations can involve nulls (e.g. ARRAY_LENGTH applied to an array with a null element) but not result in null.