# Big Query Array data type related issue if the array is NULL

Tags: google-bigquery

Please find below the table nullarraytest. The create statement:

```sql
    create table nullarraytest (name array<string>, city string);
```

The values in the table:

```sql
    insert into nullarraytest values([],"Mumbai");
    insert into nullarraytest values(["abc","def"],"Pune");
    insert into nullarraytest values(null,"Surat");
```

Issue/doubt:

1. The below query returns no data:

```sql
    select city from nullarraytest where name is NULL;
```

It should return 2 rows "Mumbai" and "Surat".

2. The below query works properly as expected:

```sql
    select city from nullarraytest where array_length(name)=0;
```

This returns 2 rows "Mumbai" and "Surat".

Why does the filter "name is null" doesn't work?

Comment: >BigQuery translates a NULL ARRAY into an empty ARRAY in the query result, although inside the query, NULL and empty ARRAYs are two distinct values.
see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_nulls

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaytiger mentioned in the comment,

It’s given in this GCP Public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_nulls) that BigQuery translates a NULL ARRAY into an empty ARRAY in the query result, although inside the query, NULL and empty ARRAYs are two distinct values. An empty array is not null. For nullable data types, NULL is a valid value. Currently, all existing data types are nullable, but conditions apply for ARRAYs.

You can also go through this [StackOverflowpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197380/unnesting-and-reforming-a-big-query-array-seems-to-destroy-null).